# Error Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff] while saving timestamp into databse

Tags: java, database, calendar, timestamp, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss a z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
String DateToStoreInDataBase= sdf.format(obj1.getSomeDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
System.out.println(emprSubDte);

Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(emprSubDte);

preparedStatement.setTimestamp(72,ts);
```

sysout of DateToStoreInDataBase is = " 2014-19-13 12:19:59 PM EDT" when i am trying to save this result into database in am getting error Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff].

I have the same format but still i am reciving the error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your SimpleDateFormat instantiation. You're using this pattern: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss a z"

The issue is in the month. It should be "MM" instead of "mm". "mm" is for "minute in the hour".

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, After changing i am getting number format exception now

Answer (score 1):

### What went wrong with your code

[`Timestamp#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) accepts the timestamp string in the format yyyy-[m]m-[d]d hh:mm:ss[.f...] while your timestamp string, `DateToStoreInDataBase` has the value 2014-19-13 12:19:59 PM EDT i.e. it has two other things `PM` (AM/PM marker) and `EDT` (time zone) - none of which are supported by this parameter.

### java.time

The `java.time` API, released with Java-8 in March 2014, supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, using this modern date-time API has been strongly recommended. Note that the class, `java.sql.Timestamp`, not only inherited those problems from its parent,  `java.util.Date` but also introduced many awful hacks.

### Solution using java.time API

If you scroll down to the bottom of [this page](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) (the same link shared above), you will find the support for `java.time` API in JDBC.

Assuming your database column is of type, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`,  the solution would be

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
                                  .toOffsetDateTime();
preparedStatement.setObject(72, odt);
```

If the column is of type, `TIMESTAMP`, the solution would be

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
preparedStatement.setObject(72, ldt);
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

here is my working successful code :

```
com.google.firebase.Timestamp currentTimeStamp = com.google.firebase.Timestamp.now();
Date ServDate = currentTimeStamp.toDate();
String currentDateStringFormated = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(ServDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

check if there is **incompatible setter or getter** , either form your database model side , view pages , beans to xhtml mapping. I found date value for float and fixed it.